# Why is adding the . at the end of aria-label considered a bad practice?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

Quick question: Why is adding the `.` at the end of `aria-label` considered a bad practice?

Relates to: [Pausing in a screen reader for accessibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15883778/pausing-in-a-screen-reader-for-accessibility/55273574#55273574)

Comment: Sorry I can't see at what point the author said it is a bad practice in that answer you linked? The original question author was using poor Markup so had to brute force it with full stops so they accepted answer is "best practice", but sometimes a full stop or comma can be useful to stop run-on in complex sentences etc.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie It's not the comment by the author of the post, it's a comment made by my co-worker. When I tried implementing the dot as suggested by the linked post, I was told it's a bad practice.

Comment: You aren't supposed to force a pause like that. If I need one, I'll configure my screen reader.
Adding a separate "." can also cause it to be read out loud as such. At the end you are bringing more problems than solving.
So avoid doing this.